# SQL : oracle 11g, Split the result set into 2 subset and display side by side

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unpivot

I did unpivot that transformed columns to rows. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc489/6

now I would like to display to student information side by side something like

```
AVGGPA      1                    1
COURSEAVG   101.5                101.5
STUDENTNAME Jilly Doe            John Doe
```

Any hints??

Comment: Why two subsets - what if you have more than two students?

Comment: Each student will be separate columns,so 3 students meaning 3 columns of student data with each column holding one student data with limit being 5 students

Comment: Pivot works here, but why struggle to use SQL for something it was not designed for? Retrieve data with SQL and let you application format and visualize it. Unless you really want plaintext SQLPlus result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only have two subsets to worry about, a simple way to build on what you have so far is:

```
SELECT labeln,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value1 END) AS col1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value1 END) AS col2
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT to_char(avg(g1.grade)) AS avgGPa,
      to_char(avg(s1.course)) AS courseAVG,
      s1.student_name AS studentName,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY s1.student_name) AS RN
    FROM student s1
    JOIN grade g1 ON s1.student_name = g1.student_name
    GROUP BY s1.student_name
  )
  UNPIVOT (value1 FOR labeln IN (avggpa, courseavg, studentname))
)
GROUP BY labeln
ORDER BY labeln;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc489/16)

It's basically a manual pivot; adding a `row_number()` to your original query, and then using that to decide which column the corresponding values go in, with `max()` to collapse the blanks. You can easily add more columns by duplicating the `max(case(...))` bit and just changing the `rn` check. But you have to know how many columns you need to end up with; or overestimate and have some blanks at the end.

In theory you could use an actual `pivot()` but you don't know the values in advance, so you don't have values to use in the `for` clause. You could maybe use an XML approach, but that's maybe overkill; depending on what your real-world usage for this would be.

Comment: Awesome Works Charming way... How do i accept your answer